# nginx passenger - issues setting environment to staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, redhat

I'm running nginx with passenger on el7

the problem i am facing is when running with staging environment i am getting constant http 500 error.

I tried all the options i could find including:

```
passenger_app_env staging; / rails_env staging; / rack_env staging;
```

i am getting constant 500 error, and i can see in the logs that i am not reaching the rails server logic.

when i am switching that configuration to:

```
rails_env development / rails_env productions
```

everything works fine.

Comment: You already have a config file `config/environments/stage.rb` with valid settings?

Comment: btw, using engineyard with the same rack_env staging works.

Comment: @Зелёный  yes, i am migrating from engineyard hosting to regular ec2....so everything works there, and i'm trying to figure out why its not working my new ec2 el7 machine.

Comment: What is the Rails error? Check it in the error log.

Comment: no error from rails....it doesn't seem to reach it....it serve the static pages, and showing 500 when trying to run a service - e.g. login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually the problem was in the staging.rb file and since i was using passenger it masked the error and just gave me 500.

eventually i moved from passenger to puma....which allowed me to debug and log rails with ease.

Comment: Hi tomerez, Passenger author here. Sorry that you had this issue. But I'm a bit confused why you couldn't figure out the problem with Passenger, and why you perceive Puma to be easier with debugging. I'm hoping you can give me some feedback so that I can improve Passenger. Passenger logs all of its problems to the Nginx error log (/var/log/nginx/error.log), [as documented](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_generic_troubleshooting_tips). Did that file not reveal the problem? Were you aware of that file in the first place?

Comment: it was easier with puma, as i was able to run it as a standalone, when running rails s.

Comment: Was there a specific reason why you didn't use Passenger in its Standalone mode? https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/ruby.html#running-the-server

Comment: yes....couldn't install it as a standlone....one of its dependencies failed, don't remember which....but  as said, it is more complicated then adding puma.rb to the config and running rails s